# vlookup run time error 1004. answer not yet found

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 5
On Error GoTo X1:
Range("F" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E" & i), Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
GoTo X2:

X1:
Range("F" & i) = "No Value found"

X2:
Next
End Sub
```

in the above code i have used the "On Eror goto " error handler. for the first time error handler works fine.but the error handler is not working for the second time.

Tables I used:

[image]

Comment: I have never seen a "run time error 1004. answer not yet found" message before - are you sure that is what it says?!?!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Rslt As Variant
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim R As Long

    Set Rng = Range("A2:B5")
    For R = 2 To 5
        Rslt = "No value found"
        On Error Resume Next
        Rslt = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(R, "E").Value, Rng, 2, 0)
        Cells(R, "F").Value = Rslt
    Next R
End Sub
```

`Rslt` is assigned the value it should have in case of unsuccessful Vlookup.
The an attempt is made to assign a lookup value to it.
If that fails `Rslt` retains the value it had before the attempt.
Meanwhile, `On Error Resume Next` allows the code to continue.
In the next line the current value of `Rslt` is assigned to the cell in column F.

- Avoid the use of `GoTo` in your code.
- Always specify a range's `Value` property when that is the property you wish to get or set.
- It's better to address a cell when you mean a cell and a range when you mean a range. True, technically a cell is a range, but reading your code will be easier if you write it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 5
On Error Resume Next:
Range("F" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E" & i), Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
If Range("F" & i) = "" Then: Range("F" & i) = "No Value Found"
Next
End Sub
```

I'd recommend using On Error Resume Next.

Now if you already have data in i = 2 to 5, Range("F" & i), then I'd recommend using

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 5
On Error Resume Next:
vall = "" 
vall = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E" & i), Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
If vall = "" Then
Range("F" & i) = "No Value Found"
Else: Range("F" & i) = vall
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Where we use the variable vall to test it VLookup returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

While you are still in error-handling mode, no more errors can be trapped.  And you were missing the `Resume` statement to exit error-handling mode:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
For i = 2 To 5
On Error GoTo X1:
Range("F" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("E" & i), Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
GoTo X2:

X1:
Range("F" & i) = "No Value found"
Resume X2  'Finished error-handling, resume normal processing
X2:
Next
End Sub
```

---

A better way to do what you are doing would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As Variant
    For i = 2 To 5
        result = Application.VLookup(Range("E" & i), Range("A2:B5"), 2, 0)
        If IsError(result) Then
            result = "No Value found"
        End If
        Range("F" & i) = result
    Next
End Sub
```

Using `Application.VLookup`, instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`, allows the error condition produced by the `VLookup` to be returned to your code, rather than causing an error in VBA itself, and once back in your code you can test for the error in a controlled fashion.